# Webview loads html in android 2.2 but not android 2.1

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a simple webview used to load a file `help3.html` when a user picks a HELP menu button.

The file loads and views well in an android 2.2 (8) emulator, but I get a `"file
//android_res/raw/help3.html not found"` error message with an Android 2.1 (7) emulator.

I am assuming that there is code in the java or xml files that version 2.1 doesn't like, and the file not found error is a fluke.

My java code to load the html file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class Help extends Activity   
{   @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
    {   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.helpview);  
    WebView mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewHelp);  
    mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/help3.html");  
    }       
}
```

and my helpview.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/webviewHelp"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not aware that `file:///android_res` is valid in any version of Android.

If you put your HTML in your project's `assets/` folder, you can use `file:///android_asset` as a prefix. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb1) demonstrates this.

Comment: Is there any official docs for these features? I can find only references in WebView and WebSettings javadocs.

Comment: @bigstones: There used to be for `android_asset`, but that seems to have been eaten in a documentation update since I last looked for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I moved the help3.html file to assets and changed the java code accordingly. Now I get the "file///android_assets/help3.html" not found message in the android 2.2 emulator as well.

Comment: @Ted Betz: You are missing a colon after `file` and have an `s` at the end of `asset` that should not be there.

Comment: Sorry about the sloppy response I typed. The java file contains:  mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/help3.html"); with the colon and the 's'. My folder was named 'assets' by Motodev.

Comment: @Ted Betz: Again, remove the `s` from the end of `asset` in the URL. The *folder* is named `assets/`, but the prefix on the URL is `file:///android_asset/` (singular). And, yes, I wish they would line up better.

Comment: That did it! The url refers to 'asset' singular even thou the folder is 'assets'. Strange stuff. Thanks!